# iPhone SDK - UITextView text color split

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` that I would like be be able to change the color for. But I would like to be able to change the color only after 50 characters. I can use `UITextViewDelegate` methods to count the characters, but I'm not sure how to change the color after that.

For instance, when I have a 100 character phrase within the `UITextView`, I would like the first 50 characters to be blue, and the last 50 characters to be red.

Is this possible? Any advice on how to achieve this?

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not via native UITextView or so

read more here:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/
http://www.scoop.it/t/iphone-and-ipad-development/p/104023127/rtlabel-rich-text-formatting-for-ios-using-html-like-markup-coding-for-mobile
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/display-rich-text-using-a-uiwebview

like @Nekto said

Comment: The link to the project in the first link (http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/) is broken, fyi.

Comment: @chown no, it's not. maybe they had a little outage, but I can see the page clearly now

Comment: The page itself works, but the link inside that *should* take you to the github project: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML gives a 404 error.  Still has useful info though, so not a huge deal.

Answer (score 0):

You can set only **one** color for **all** characters in one text view, using `textColor` property. If you want different colors in one sequence of characters, you can use, for example, `UIWebView` and html tags.